# Why do I get slaveOkay = 0; Timeout = 30000 MongoPHP

Tags: php, mongodb, xdebug

I am using Mac, netbeans, x-debug, with Mongo PHP. I am trying to run a basic search like:

```
$results = $mongo->$col->find();
```

However during debug, the value for $results is slaveOkay = 0 and timeout = 30000. Why is this so? Some version information about the tools installed are:

> PHP 5.4.20 (cli) (built: Sep 24 2013 10:10:10) (DEBUG) Copyright (c)
>   1997-2013 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013
>   Zend Technologies
>       with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
>
> MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6

Thanks.

Comment: These appear to be values that belong to the driver to manage itself... how exactly do these values look like? Can you iterate the actual result set?

Comment: No, there is nothing else in property $results besides: slaveOkay boolean 0 and timeout 30000. No other results and no errors either. Those values are just what I see under debug mode in $results variable.

Answer (score 0):

Where does that `$col` variable come from?
And where does `$mongo` come from?

The correct way to query a collection is

```
<?php
$mongo = new MongoClient(...);
$collection = $mongo->databaseName->collectionName;
$results = $collection->find();
?>
```

Then you can iterate over `$results` like so:

```
foreach($results as $document) {
    /* Do something with $document */
}
```

See http://php.net/mongocollection.find and http://php.net/mongo.queries for more details